# RecyclerView inaccurate first completely visible item index if clipToPadding="false"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

i have a `RecyclerView` with top padding and `android:clipToPadding="false"`

when `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` is called on the `RecyclerView`'s `LinearLayoutManager`, it returns the index of the first item that would be completely visible if `android:clipToPadding` were set to `true`.

Any idea how to get the first actually completely visible item index if `android:clipToPadding` is set to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't get it to work with `LinearLayoutManager#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`, but i figured out another solution.

Since I just needed to know how much the `RecyclerView`'s top was offset, i used `RecyclerView#computeVerticalScrollOffset()`. Even though `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` **estimates** how much scrollable space is left, since i just needed to know how much was offset close to the top, it's good enough

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. After researching a lot, I found a solution for this problem. Instead of using `findXVisibleItemPosition` methods of **LinearLayoutManager** first, I found these positions using `getPosition` method of **LayoutManager**. I also used `findXVisibleItemPosition` method in case child views are null.

The solution is:

```
val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager

val firstChild = layoutManager.getChildAt(0)
val firstIndex = firstChild
    ?.let { layoutManager.getPosition(it) }
    ?: layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

val lastChild = layoutManager.getChildAt(layoutManager.childCount - 1)
val lastIndex = lastChild
    ?.let { layoutManager.getPosition(it) }
    ?: layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

Log.d("First index: $firstIndex, last index: $lastIndex")
```

Comment: If you are only interested in partially visible items, this works fine